# How do i change the name on nginx hls file?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, http-live-streaming

I've successfully set up my configuration file for Nginx which works almost perfectly, using this tutorial.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-nginx-on-ubuntu-to-stream-live-hls-video

The only problem is that the file name that it outputs is "index.m3u8" and I would want it to be "playlist.m3u8" instead.

my url currently looks like this for accessing the stream.
https://myurl.com/live/test/index.m3u8
and what i would want is https://myurl.com/live/test/playlist.m3u8

Here is my config file :)

```html
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  logs/error.log debug;

events {
 worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
 server {
 listen 1935;
 allow play all;

#creates our "live" full-resolution HLS videostream from our incoming encoder stream and tells where to put the HLS video manifest and video fragments
 application live {
  allow play all;
  live on;
  record off;
  hls on;
  hls_nested on;
  hls_path /HLS/live;
  hls_fragment 10s;

 #creates the downsampled or "trans-rated" mobile video stream as a 400kbps, 480x360 sized video
  exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name -acodec copy -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline -vsync cfr -s 480x360 -b:v 400k maxrate 400k -bufsize 400k -threads 0 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/mobile/$;
 }

#creates our "mobile" lower-resolution HLS videostream from the ffmpeg-created stream and tells where to put the HLS video manifest and video fragments
 application mobile {
  allow play all;
  live on;
  hls on;
  hls_nested on;
  hls_path /HLS/mobile;
  hls_fragment 10s;
 }

 # #allows you to play your recordings of your live streams using a URL like "rtmp://my-ip:1935/vod/filename.flv"
 # application vod {
 # play /video_recordings;
 # }
 }
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

#creates the http-location for our full-resolution (desktop) HLS stream - "http://my-ip/live/my-stream-key/index.m3u8"      
location /live {
 types {
  application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
 }
 alias /HLS/live;
 add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
}

#creates the http-location for our mobile-device HLS stream - "http://my-ip/mobile/my-stream-key/index.m3u8"        
location /mobile {
 types {
  application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
 }
 alias /HLS/mobile;
 add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
}   

#allows us to see how stats on viewers on our Nginx site using a URL like: "http://my-ip/stats"     
location /stats {
 stub_status;
}
#allows us to host some webpages which can show our videos: "http://my-ip/my-page.html"     
location / { 
 root   html;
 index  index.html index.htm;
}   
}
}
```

I would appreciate all the help i can get.

Regards Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an easy workaround, you can create a symlink from `index.m3u8` to `playlist.m3u8`

```
exec ln -sf /HLS/$app/$name/index.m3u8 /HLS/$app/$name/playlist.m3u8;
```

Add it inside the `application live` block

```
application live {
        allow play all;
        live on;
        record off;
        hls on;
        hls_nested on;
        hls_path /HLS/live;
        hls_fragment 10s;

        #creates the downsampled or "trans-rated" mobile video stream as a 400kbps, 480x360 sized video
        exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name -acodec copy -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -profile:v baseline -vsync cfr -s 480x360 -b:v 400k maxrate 400k -bufsize 400k -threads 0 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/mobile/$;
        exec ln -sf /HLS/$app/$name/index.m3u8 /HLS/$app/$name/playlist.m3u8;
}
```